# string variable not being recognized in replyTo argument for sendmail

Tags: sendmail

Everything in this script call to sendEmail works fine, but the replyTo is not being honored.  Have printed out the string I want to use and all is correct but the email received doesn't have the correct replyTo.  What gives?

```
GmailApp.sendEmail(row[RECIPIENT_COL], msgObj.subject, msgObj.text, {
      htmlBody: msgObj.html,
      // bcc: 'a.bbc@email.com',
      // cc: 'a.cc@email.com',
      from: 'admin@rosegarden-na.org',
      name: 'RGNA Steering Committee',
      replyTo: new_reply_to,
      // noReply: true, // if the email should be sent from a generic no-reply email address (not available to gmail.com users)
      attachments: emailTemplate.attachments
    });

new_reply_to string value is correct but is not in the email sent
```

Answer (score 0):

Using replyTo in the GmailApp.sendEmail will NOT override a reply to that was established in the account settings.

Once I removed it, the script worked fine.